# how can i solve the problem problem with this regex?

Tags: regex, grok

what is the problem with this regex?

```
  PUBLIC_API_REQUEST:http://localhost:6501/public/api/v1/getBranches/client/faraApp {some text 
  here} PUBLIC_API_RESPONSE:{some text here}

 myregex :PUBLIC_API_REQUEST:(?<address>(?:[A-z\:\-\0-9\/]+)) (?<requestBody>[^}]*) 
 PUBLIC_API_RESPONSE:(?<response>[^}]*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match and consume the text that you are not going to capture, like `{` or `{` chars.

Also, the `[A-z]` is [not matching just letters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926), it is simpler and less confusing to use `%{NOTSPACE:address}` (matching a streak of non-whitespace chars) instead of `(?<address>(?:[A-z\:\-\0-9\/]+))`.

You can use

```
PUBLIC_API_REQUEST:%{NOTSPACE:address} +\{(?<requestBody>[^{}]*)} +PUBLIC_API_RESPONSE:\{(?<response>[^{}]*)}
```

Test screenshot:

[image]